# How to use check box in select list for multiple selection in content type?

Tags: entities, nodes

I simply want a select list like this.[image]

Is there any options to add a field like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply achieve that by following way.

Choose Field Widget Type '*Checkbox*' instead of *Select list*.

If you want to make appear checkboxes field as multiple select list,Add the following line in your CSS file

```
   #field-id-name{ height: 100px; overflow: auto; width: 100px;  }
```

Note: replace `field-id-name` with id name of the field; change the width and height according to your requirement.

After applying CSS, the checkbox list field in content type appears as follows.

[image]

I hope this simple solution helps

Comment: It works fine sir:)

Comment: Sure sir.Its useful for me:)

Answer (score 1):

Try [Dropdown Checkboxes](https://drupal.org/project/dropdown_checkboxes) module

> This module helps to convert multiple select lists into dropdown checkboxes using ddcl library.

Comment: I enabled this module..But it have an option as like before

Comment: Follow README.txt under module directory. This requires ddcl library.

Comment: I have one more doubt sir.Where I should put ddcl library..Have to put inside the Dropdown Checkboxes module ah..

Comment: No,Place that under sites/all/libraries and rename the extracted library to ddcl

Comment: actually library module is there..but ddcl contains cc,js,doc,src folder..where it should be put?

Comment: sorry sir..I got it

Comment: But still  I didn't get what i expected.

Comment: @Dhivya I've posted another answer below. I hope it helps. I've tested in on my local and works great!